# Add text inside DateTime.ToString with C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to add a 'at' inside my DateTime format string but every time I try it messes it up?

```
origin.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy at HH:mm:ss");
```

When its this it works fine... but looks a bit ugly.

```
origin.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`t` is a custom format specifier and will be replaced with `A` or `P` based on the time of day.

> `t` The first character of the AM/PM designator.

You can prevent that from happening by escaping it with `\`.

```
origin.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy a\t HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: I think that you need to surround the character you want to escape by quotes.
Example: DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd-hh\'h'mm\'m'ss\'s'")

Answer (score 15):

add escape sequence:

```
origin.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy 'at' HH:mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 0):

You may add the following code:

```
System.DateTime.Now.Date.ToString() + "at" + System.DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString()
```

and then use this in your code.